# How to recompile jar file from command line

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, jar

I have a jar file that consists of class files and java source files together (actually android unity plugin).

I want change the behaviour of one of the function  by modifying the java source code and repackage it to jar file. Is it feasible to do with command line?

Comment: You could start from here [Using JAR Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html). If you have congrete problem, come back and tell what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Use `jar xf <JAR-file>` to extract the entire JAR file to whatever directory you're currently on.

Add your new code to the files, removing the old code (make sure you have copies or back everything up, just in case).

Use `jar cvf <JAR-file-name> *` to create a JAR using all contents in the directory of your files.